# boost build: "lib" directory not created after running "bjam install"

Tags: boost

I've built boost with these commands:

`bootstrap`

`b2 --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage`

After that `boost` is built but there are no `lib` folder in it. To create `lib` folder i've tried to run

`bjam install`

But this doesn't help. What command should I run to create `lib` folder?

**upd** I've succesfully installed libs with this command `bjam --prefix=. install` but by some reason not all libs were installed, but only "libboost*.lib"... The question now is why I do have "libboost*.lib" files in `lib` folder but `*.dll` files are missing..

Comment: `stage` means you want to put the libs in `stage` directory

Comment: right but `bjam install` should install these libs.

Comment: If you think something is wrong, try "-d+2" as part of your command line.

Answer (score -1):

Boost has a `libs` folder, not a `lib` folder. The object files are stored in `bin.v2/libs/library_name/compiler_name/build/(debug or release)/link-static/threading-multi`. Boost doesn't use DLLs, but it uses object files. These are linked with your program at build time by using bjam/b2.
Also, what compiler are you using, and have you configured it in your user-config.jam? Also, the directory holding bootstrap should house the following directories: `bin.v2, boost, doc, libs, more, stage, status, tools`.